# i can't show span in function - javascript

Tags: javascript, function

i don't know how i can used if inside function then show it by span in html.

this my function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="praytimes.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function ptt() {
    var date = new Date(); // today
    var dhours = new Date().toTimeString().split(" ")[0];   
    var PT = new PrayTimes('Makkah');
    var times = PT.getTimes(date, [24.46666, 39.59998], +3);    
    if (times.fajr > dhours){    
        document.getElementById("pyr").innerHTML = '<center>الفجر <br/>'+ times.fajr + '</center>';
    } else if (times.sunrise > dhours){  
        document.getElementById("pyr").innerHTML = '<center>الإشراق <br/>'+ times.sunrise + '</center>';
    } else if (times.dhuhr > dhours){    
        document.getElementById("pyr").innerHTML = '<center>الظهر <br/>'+ times.dhuhr + '</center>';
    } else if (times.asr > dhours){ 
        document.getElementById("pyr").innerHTML = '<center>العصر <br/>'+ times.asr + '</center>';
    } else if (times.maghrib > dhours){ 
        document.getElementById("pyr").innerHTML = '<center>المغرب <br/>'+ times.maghrib + '</center>';
    } else if (times.isha > dhours){    
        document.getElementById('pyr').innerHTML+='<center>العشاء <br/>'+ times.isha + '</center>'; 
    } else if (times.midnight > dhours){
        //document.write('<br/>العشاء = '+ times.midnight);
        document.getElementById('pyr').innerHTML+='<center>منتصف الليل '+ times.midnight + '</center>'; 
    }   
}

setTimeout('ptt()',1000);

</script>
```

and this tag in html:

```
<span id='pyr'></span>
```

but i can't show the result in html.

Comment: That $ symbol in your script represents jquery, have you added that to your script tag?

Comment: no jquery in the code.

Comment: now i corrected the answer by add: setTimeout('ptt()',1000);   , Best Regards

Comment: please: the last else which containt "times.midnight" not work ?! what is the wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can access a specific HTML element using the **getElementById()** method.
In your case the span's ID is pyr:

```
document.getElementById("pyr");
```

Now simply replace document.write() by document.getElementById("pyr").innerHTML+="your content here";

For example:

```
document.write('<br/>fa = '+ times.fajr);
```

becomes

```
document.getElementById("pyr").innerHTML+="<br/>fa = "+ times.fajr;
```

Comment: thank you, i add it but not work, mabe another problem in the code?

Comment: Ah, I guess I see what's going on after having a look at your updated code in the question. Do you see the following line: `document.write(dhours)` (and also the later `document.write('<br/>منتصف الليل = '+ times.midnight);` ) What you're doing here is overwriting your whole DOM with the value of **dhours** - that means everything and your span element will be gone! Try commenting out those two document.write() calls.

Comment: i deleted line 6: document.write(dhours), but not worked.

Comment: Well the last thing that I see is that your function doesn't actually have a name - which is required. How are you calling that function?

Comment: now i corrected the answer by add: setTimeout('ptt()',1000);   , Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you call the function, at least not in the code you provided. Try to give your function a name and then call it.

```
function funcName () { ... }

funcname()
```

Comment: now i corrected the answer by add: setTimeout('ptt()',1000);   , Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

please i added new code to read lat and lng from gps:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
    var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
    var lng = pos.coords.longitude;
    if (lat == null) {
        var lat = 24.46666;
        var lng = 39.59998;
    } else {
        alert("Latitude: "+ lat + " , Longitude: " + lng );
    }
});

var date = new Date(); // today
var dhours = new Date().toTimeString().split(" ")[0];   
var PT = new PrayTimes('Makkah');
var times = PT.getTimes(date, [lat, lng], +3);
```

but this line:

```
var times = PT.getTimes(date, [lat, lng], +3);
```

can't read lat and lng from this lines:

```
    if (lat == null) {
        var lat = 24.46666;
        var lng = 39.59998;
```

please what is the wronge?